# Compress all files in all subfolders matching a pattern

Tags: bash, shell, unix, tar

In my root folder, there are many subfolders named `data_x`, `data_easy`, `data_real`, ...
Each of them has a different hierarchy of subfolders.
I need to compress files in ALL subfolders that match a pattern, in my case `*test*.npy` (all numpy files with 'test' in their name).

Currently, I do

```bash
shopt -s globstar; tar -czvf data.tar.gz data*/**/*test*.npy
```

But it is VERY slow. Sometimes it is faster to just compress ALL files without matching the pattern with `**/*test*.npy`. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Is the problem with compression or with listing all the files? How fast is `echo data*/**/*test*.npy > /dev/null`?

Comment: Listing. Your command is also very slow. The solutions suggested by Philippe works, so I guess that `**` is very slow, not sure why.

Comment: `**`, unlike `find`, sorts its output; and because you're putting the glob on an argv, the argv has to be completely known before tar can be started. The `find` operation can start writing results as soon as it finds them; the glob has to complete finding _all_ the filenames before it can sort them, and only then can it invoke `tar`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Perfect, thanks for the info!

Comment: (Philippe's answer is also good because it can work with a longer list of filenames than fits on a command line -- so performance isn't the only reason to use that approach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to see if there is performance improvement :

```
find data* -type f -name "*test*.npy" -print0 | tar -czvf data.tar.gz --null -T -
```

Comment: Much faster, thanks! Can you explain why `**` is so much slower?

Comment: @Simon The shell sorts the filenames. This can be slow if there are lots of them.

Comment: Not only that, but in the pipeline the `find` can still be running when `tar` begins operation, but with the glob the two steps are serial.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for the explanation!